# How to deploy an update to your PHP server atomically, i.e. preserving consistency?

Tags: php, deployment, webserver

Let's say you run a PHP + database server and you want to deploy an update that modifies the database schema and the PHP sources. You do it regularly.

The problem is that during the update your service will be briefly put in an inconsistent state and as a result clients will get random errors. Firstly it's the inconsistencies across DB tables while updating the schema, then inconsistencies between the DB and your source, and finally while updating the sources themselves: your files will become empty or partial for very brief moments, then inconsistent across modules themselves. There is a chance your clients might be getting errors during the update.

The question is, what is the best way to prevent this?

The solution I'm thinking of: replace the server's root `.htaccess` with  one that returns HTTP `503 Service unavailable` for the duration of the update, then put the original back (say a script will do all this). Clients can retry within a few seconds, for example 503 for them means retry within 10 seconds, no more than 3 times.

One potential problem is having some requests already in progress before htaccess is swapped, so need a way of waiting until all requests are handled. Most problematic will be long file transfers. Say it takes minutes to serve a file to a client, it means the server will be in a 503 state for minutes.

Also, are there any out of the box solutions specifically for PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You have two servers. Run the updates on the failover, then fail over, run the updates on the main box and fail back. You could even just spin up a cloud instance of your server to take traffic while you update your server. I suppose it depends on what the downtime will cost you. If it's not going to cost much to do down for a while; point your dns at Google or something!

If this is an income; I would suggest setting up two servers anyway, so you have one to fall back on when something goes wrong!